text_frame.place() Not displaying text box
Attempting to display a text box, was displaying with .pack() but .place() isn't making. I don't want to use .pack() because of padding; I'd rather .place() because of relx and rely.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import time


def typewriter_effect(text_widget, text, buttons):
    for button in buttons:
        button.place_forget()  # Hide buttons while typing
    for char in text:
        text_widget.insert(tk.END, char)
        text_widget.see(tk.END)
        text_widget.update()
        time.sleep(0.05)
    for button in buttons:
        button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.CENTER)  # Show buttons after typing

def explore_room():
    messagebox.showinfo("Exploration", "You explored the room. You found a key!")

def go_back_to_sleep():
    messagebox.showinfo("Back to Sleep", "You went back to sleep. Zzz...")

def look_for_light_switch():
    messagebox.showinfo("Light Switch", "You found the light switch. The room is now illuminated.")

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Text Adventure Game")
    root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)

    text_options_frame = tk.Frame(root, bd=2, relief=tk.RIDGE)
    text_options_frame.pack(expand=True)

    text_frame = tk.Frame(text_options_frame, bd=0)
    text_frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.7, anchor=tk.CENTER)  # Placing at the bottom center

    text_scroll = tk.Scrollbar(text_frame)
    text_scroll.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

    text_widget = tk.Text(text_frame, wrap=tk.WORD, yscrollcommand=text_scroll.set, height=10, width=120, font=("Helvetica", 12))
    text_widget.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

    text_scroll.config(command=text_widget.yview)

    button_frame = tk.Frame(root)
    button_frame.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, pady=10)

    explore_button = tk.Button(button_frame, text="Explore the room", command=explore_room)
    sleep_button = tk.Button(button_frame, text="Go back to sleep", command=go_back_to_sleep)
    light_button = tk.Button(button_frame, text="Look for a light switch", command=look_for_light_switch)

    typewriter_effect(text_widget, "Welcome to the Text Adventure Game!\n\n"
                                    "You find yourself in a dark room. What would you like to do?\n",
                                    [explore_button, sleep_button, light_button])
    
    delay([explore_button, sleep_button, light_button], 1)
    explore_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5)
    sleep_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5)
    light_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5)
    delay([explore_button], 1)
    explore_button.pack_forget()
    root.mainloop()


def delay(button, wait):
    for widget in button:
        widget.update()
    time.sleep(wait)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Tried using .place() but text box won't display, seems like the text is writing in the text box because the buttons are set to appear after the text is finished writing.

You need to explicitly give the Frame a size.  .place() won't automatically do that for you, like .grid() and .pack() do.

@jasonharper Adding width and height doesn't work, is there another way that I don't know of or am I doing it wrong? Also, by your explanation "button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.CENTER)" also wouldn't work but it does.

annoying following tkinter code that does not have type hints. For example,  what is text_widget in the typewriter_effect() function ?

@jasonharper is correct, as he stated, the Frame widget will not be given a size automatically by the place() manager.  Your attempt to compare a Button widget to the Frame widget is flawed as they are not treated the same.

I think what you need is adding fill=tk.BOTH to text_options_frame.pack(...).



text_frame.place() Not displaying text box

Attempting to display a text box, was displaying with .pack() but
.place() isn't making. I don't want to use .pack() because of padding;
I'd rather .place() because of relx and rely

The problem can be fixed.
Comment out on line 32 and 33 in main() function.
Used the text_frame for Text widget.
I added color to the background and foreground. So, we can determine the frame position.
Snippet:
def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Text Adventure Game")
    root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)   

    #text_options_frame = tk.Frame(root, bd=2, relief=tk.RIDGE)
    #text_options_frame.pack(expand=True)

    text_frame = tk.Frame(root, bd=2, relief=tk.RIDGE)
    text_frame.place(relx=0.63, rely=0.7, anchor=tk.CENTER)  # Placing at the bottom center

    text_scroll = tk.Scrollbar(text_frame)
    text_scroll.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

    text_widget = tk.Text(text_frame, wrap=tk.WORD, bg='blue', fg='white', yscrollcommand=text_scroll.set, height=10, width=120, font=("Helvetica", 12))
    text_widget.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

:
:
:

Screenshot:

